# Managing GIT branches between active development and production build

Tags: git

I'm trying to find the best approach to this situation, I've seen some online but I'm not sure they match my situation.

We have 2 branches, we do our development on master and we just had release 1. We made a new branch called Release 1, so we can have a reference in case of bug fixes while we continue working on Release 2.

So my problem is, 2 weeks later release 2 is full of new changes, and I need a fix on release 1...

Do I just make the change on both branches on this point or do I make the change on the master branch and somehow merge(cherry pick) into the release 1 branch? My problem with the second is that the file needing change may be very different, causing a conflict and ultimately a different commit on the release 1 branch that we never plan on moving to master...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on lifetime of your fixes. If they are permanent you should fix them in master and merge to all releases and fix conflicts. In this case cherry-pick is suitable. But if they need only in release 1 do it there and don't merge to another branches.

Comment: Thanks, they would be needed on master as well - since most likely it's a bug that was found and still exists in the current development branch..